# Add column based on other columns values

Tags: r

I am honest, I could come up with a decent title for this.
Basically, I have a `dateframe`:

```
ID Qty BasePrice Total
1   2     30      50
1   1     20      20
2   4      5      15
```

For each line I want to calculate the following:

```
Result = (Qty * BasePrice) - Total
```

Which is supposedly easy to do in R. However, I want to group the results by `ID` (sum them).

Sample Output:

```
ID Qty BasePrice Total Results
1   2     30      50     10
1   1     20      20     10
2   4      5      15     5
```

For instance, for `ID=1`, the values represent `((2*30)-50)+((1*20)-20)`

Any idea on how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are selecfting the sum value per group, then `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Result = sum((Qty * BasePrice) - Total))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `group_by` `sum` of the difference between the product of 'Qty', 'BasePrice' with 'Total'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Result = sum((Qty * BasePrice) - Total))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID   Qty BasePrice Total Result
#  <int> <int>     <int> <int>  <int>
#1     1     2        30    50     10
#2     1     1        20    20     10
#3     2     4         5    15      5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L), Qty = c(2L, 1L, 4L), BasePrice = c(30L, 
 20L, 5L), Total = c(50L, 20L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: `library(magrittr)` as well for the pipe operator (`%>%`)

Comment: @NickDylla  When you call `dplyr`, the pipe will be exported

Comment: Out of habit I still call `library(magrittr)`, which I think is still helpful to note for new R users. It provides a route to learn more about piping within `dplyr` functions.